# Show that $0.01<\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{5}{7}\times\frac{11}{13}\times . . . \times \frac{9967}{9973}< 0.02$ without brute force.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Show that $0.01<p=\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{5}{7}\times\frac{11}{13}\times . . . \times \frac{9967}{9973}< 0.02$, where numbers on numerator and denominator are all  primes less than $10000$, without brute force.(Number of these primes is $1240$).

My attempt: We can see that:

$P=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{4}\times \frac {5}{6}\times . . . \times\frac{9999}{10000}<0.01$;

Consider :

$P=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{4}\times \frac{5}{6}\times . . . \times \frac{2n-1}{2n}$

We know that $\frac {a+1}{b+1}>\frac{a}{b}$; $a, b ∈\mathbb N $, so we may write:

$P<\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{3}{5}\times \frac{6}{7}\times . . . \times \frac{2n}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)P}$

⇒ $P^2<\frac{1}{2n+1}<\frac{1}{2n}$ ⇒ $P<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$

Now due to statement if we assume $n=5000$, then we have:

$P<\frac{1}{\sqrt{10000}}=0.01$

Clearly $p>P$. For RHS of inequality if we let $p=0.01$ we may approximate the upper bound as:

$\frac{10000+1240}{10000}\times 0.01=0.001124$

I think there must be a better algorithm for RHS. Any help or idea ?

Comment: This is not clear.  There are many such $a$.  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: OK, I mean minimum possible a, I edited my question.

Comment: Finding the "minimum possible $a$" means computing the product exactly.  I don't think that is a realistic goal (well, it's trivial with a computer...$0.00783054$).

Comment: @lulu, to be precise (as I'm sure you know), there is no minimum $a$ satisfying the *strict* inequality $p\lt a$. (I do wonder whether the OP's tacit infinite product tends to a nonzero limit.)

Comment: @BarryCipra Yeah, I wondered about that.  I ran the product for the first $50,000$ terms and got $0.00218866$ so it is still dropping fast out there.  No proof of anything, of course.

Comment: Note:  there was a silly bug in my computation from above, it went out far too many terms.  The correct product (for the expression in the post) should have been $0.0179037$ and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%28product%28prime%5B2n%2B1%5D%2Fprime%5B2n%2B2%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C1110%7D%29%29) is the Wolfram Alpha version of the computation.

Comment: Thank you guys, you gave me an idea to improve the question. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @lulu, that wolfram calc starts with 5/7 not 3/5

Comment: @dm63  Yes, thank you.  And my limits are still wrong as well.   I appear determined to botch this simple computation.  Though...$p_{1221}=9901$  and $p_{1222} = 9907$ so I'm not sure how that works out...from the starting terms it looks as though the numerators should be the even indexed primes, but that doesn't fit the last term.  Or perhaps I am making more careless errors.

Comment: @lulul, you are right, the OP has the wrong last term

Comment: @lulu, I corrected the last term.

Comment: @sirous  I don't see how that edit helps.  Now the numerator is $p_{1227}$ and $1227$ is still odd, so there is the same problem.  In any case, if you go to the WA link I posted you can set the limits however you like and get the value.  I don't see a sensible analytic way to avoid a hard computation, but of course I might just be missing it.

Comment: @lulu, sorry for numerous edits, I think the question is now OK.

Comment: @sirious  Like I say, you can edit my WA link to do the thing by brute force.  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%28product%28prime%5B2n%5D%2Fprime%5B2n%2B1%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C614%29%29) is what I now believe to match your latest edit but I advise checking it carefully.  Just to say, you need $240$ terms in the product to get to $.02$...I just don't think it is easy.

Comment: p can roughly be $\frac{1240}{10000}\times 0.01=0.0124$

Comment: @lulu You can have the limits correct automatically by using PrimePi (thre is still something wrong with your limits I think), see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BProduct%5BPrime%5B2+n+-+1%5D%2FPrime%5B2+n%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+PrimePi%5B10000%5D%7D%5D%5D)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  Oh, I don't doubt it.  I made so many careless errors on this simple computation that I just stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda nonsensical.

1. Suppose you're asking for the minimum natural number $a$, such that $p = \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{7}{11} \cdots \frac{9901}{9907} < a$. We have $0 < p < 1$, since $p$ equals the product of numbers, and each of them lies in $(0, 1)$. Therefore, $a=1$.
2. Suppose you're asking for the minimum rational number $a$ satisfying the aforementioned inequality. $p$ is also rational. For any two different rational numbers there exists another rational number that lies between them. Therefore, no such $a$ exists, since if we choose some $a > p$, there must exists $b$ such that $a>b>p$.
3. Suppose you're asking for the minimum real number $a$ satisfying the aforementioned inequality. Such $a$ doesn't exist, proof is the same as the previous item, except you replace the word rational with the word real everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an amateurish attempt:
$p=\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{7}{11}\times\frac{13}{17}\times . . . \times \frac{9901}{9907}$

Now let $q=\frac{5}{7}\times\frac{11}{13}\times\frac{17}{19}\times . . . \times \frac{9907}{9923}$

Clearly $pq = 3/9923$, but also $p<q$ (obvious?) hence $p<\sqrt(3/9923)=0.017...$

Comment: Why is $p<q$? Not all terms in $p$ are smaller than corresponding terms in $q$. For instance, the first terms after the ones you wrote are $19/23$ in $p$ and $23/29$ in $q$, and $19/23>23/29$.

Comment: @wojowu you are correct I have not proved it.  It seems to be true in general that the ratio of successive primes gets closer to 1 as n increases , and since the q series has larger numbers, it makes sense for it to be larger.  But not proven.